# How to store base64 as an image in file system in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, save

As above, how do I store in the file system?

I have tried these solutions, but I have still not got it right...
https://gist.github.com/madhums/e749dca107e26d72b64d#file-base64-image-upload-js-L7
https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC-_K2yIPOAhVJRY8KHUq5D4oQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F17397319%2Fsave-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop&usg=AFQjCNGADOLxAdsduTuK6d-ZcVzZRgGwWg&sig2=UPC0l9bSsPGASnCrM94unA

All I need to save looks something like this.

```
Object {imageFormat: "image/jpeg", imageB64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAw…J3kdq5LxJM7X8ik5CyMB+dFFOPxGNT4DNJOetFFFbnCf/2Q=="}imageB64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQE...+dFFOPxGNT4DNJOetFFFbnCf/2Q=="imageFormat: "image/jpeg"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: __proto__()set __proto__: __proto__()
```

Copied the whole object there..

Just picking up Javascript so please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Im wondering if "window.location='http://  data:image/jpeg;base64,'+img;" works

Comment: @Jonasw How should this code be actually written?

Comment: img should be the base64 string. Then just put this line into your js

Comment: @Jonasw the page just turns into an empty page.. help?

Comment: @Jonasw And I am not sure why you are adding the prefixes, data type and base64 into the image when the image object already contains them.

Comment: Oh made a mistake try it without http://

Comment: @Jonasw Getting this error now..

This site can’t be reached

The webpage at data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object] might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: @Jonasw I guess what u wanted me to do and did this,

window.location='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+result.imageB64; but it just changes the URL to the image and das not what I want, I want to be able to store it.

Comment: Jep. I realised that. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply open the base64 in a new tab using javascript:

```
window.location="data:image/jpeg;base64,ehfnshxfbsnxj";
```

To let the browser download it automatically use this snippet found on SO:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');  
link.href = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,sduebdueb'; link.download = 'coolimage.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Comment: I did your solution, however, the download fails and I am unable to download it, how may I add an image into the comment to show u?

I did the following code,  link.download = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+result.imageB64;
and link.download = result;

Comment: Oh sorry, ive made a mistake

Comment: The link.href is the important one not the link.download

Comment: @Jonasw, if you agree with Ming Jin, you should accept his/her edit, or edit it yourself to provide the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var link = document.createElement('a');  
    link.href = img; 
    link.download = 'filename.jpeg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
```

This is the solution to automatically download an image, first you create a link element, then you append the image object to href attribute and append the filename to download attribute and it should work.